# Is it possible to check if certain CSS properties are defined inside the style tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I'm writing a script that needs to check if certain CSS properties are defined inside the `<style>` tag.

```css
<style type="text/css">
#bar {width: 200px;}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="width: 200px;">foo</div>
<div id="bar">bar</div>
```

```javascript
// 200px
console.log(document.getElementById("foo").style.width);

// an empty string
console.log(document.getElementById("bar").style.width);

if(property_width_defined_in_style_tag) {
    // ...
}
```

Is this possible?

I'm not trying to get the `getComputedStyle(ele).width` btw.

Comment: *"I'm not trying to get the getComputedStyle(ele).width btw."* And yet, your code examples suggest that's exactly what you're trying to do. If it isn't, what *are* you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get some string (200px in this case) instead of "an empty string" from #bar since the style was defined in the style tag.

Comment: @ user: That's what `getComputedStyle` would do.

Comment: Crowder, please read the title, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. `getComputedStyle` will for sure return some real value, but you cannot tell where the style was defined, either from the style tag or inline style. @dystroy's suggestion might be the solution.

Comment: @ user: I saw the title. You need to understand that people say X and mean Y **all the time**. Yes, absolutely, look through the stylesheets if you think that's the best approach. Another might be to compare the `style` object to the return value from `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: Keep in mind that you could have the same property defined in both inline style *and* stylesheet, and depends by the "!important" they could be applied differently. Plus, that you could have something not defined for `#bar` in the stylesheet, but defined for `div`, and the `width` will be applied too (if you're planning to have generic selectors, you could have also "div#bar" or cascading selector and so on that won't match).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want, it works closest to your first pseudo code where you had an element instance, anyway hope it helps:

```
var proto = Element.prototype;
var slice = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
var matches = Function.call.bind(proto.matchesSelector || 
                proto.mozMatchesSelector || proto.webkitMatchesSelector ||
                proto.msMatchesSelector || proto.oMatchesSelector);

// Returns true if a DOM Element matches a cssRule
var elementMatchCSSRule = function(element, cssRule) {
  return matches(element, cssRule.selectorText);
};

// Returns true if a property is defined in a cssRule
var propertyInCSSRule = function(prop, cssRule) {
  return prop in cssRule.style && cssRule.style[prop] !== "";
};

// Here we get the cssRules across all the stylesheets in one array
var cssRules = slice(document.styleSheets).reduce(function(rules, styleSheet) {
  return rules.concat(slice(styleSheet.cssRules));
}, []);

// get a reference to an element, then...
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");

// get only the css rules that matches that element
var elementRules = cssRules.filter(elementMatchCSSRule.bind(null, bar));

// check if the property "width" is in one of those rules
hasWidth = elementRules.some(propertyInCSSRule.bind(null, "width"));
```

I think you can reuse all of this code for your purpose, or just some piece of it, it's modular on purpose – for instance, once you have all the `cssRules` flatten, or the `elementRules`, you can still use a `for` loop and check what you need.
It uses ES5 functions and [matchesSelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.mozMatchesSelector) so in old browsers won't work without shims. Plus, you could also filter by priority and so on – you could for instance remove all the properties has a lower priority than the inline style ones, etc.

Comment: ZER0, I still don't quite get how your code works. But, this is **exactly** what I want. And the best part is that it works on `parent child {prop: val}` where child is an element tag name, instead of a class or id selector. Answer Accpeted. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried to put some meaningful comments in the code, but if there are some part you want to be explained better just let me know. Glad it was the code you was looking for!

Comment: I've updated a modified version of your code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567761/how-to-display-all-css-selectors-properties-in-a-textarea/50569764# Maybe you'll want to see it!

Comment: @TakitIsy hey, thanks! Glad to see it's still used and helpful. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can completely explore in javascript the [styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/stylesheet).

Start with the `document.styleSheets` array. The values are the different style elements or CSS files that are used by your document.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation...and it seems that I have to perform a regular expression on each of style sheets. one small correction...`document.styleSheets`, capitalized `S` for `Sheets`.

Comment: Why would you do a regular expression ? I certainly don't need regular expression when [reading styleSheets from js](https://github.com/Canop/braldop/blob/master/src/gui/SpriteSet.js).

Comment: That was my first thought when I console log `document.styleSheets`. Problem has been solved and question has been updated. Thanks.

Comment: dystroy, thanks for the styleSheets tip. I found ZER0's solution is exactly what I need. So I chose his answer as accepted. Sorry about that.